# I get an error while re-indexing catalog_category_product M2

Tags: reindex, magento2.4.6, mariadb

During the reindexing catalog_category_product index gives an error
`query_timeout exceeded`

```
  INSERT INTO `catalog_category_product_index_store2_tmp` (`category_id`, `product_id`, `position`, `is_parent`, `store_id`, `visibility`) SELECT `cc`.`entity_id` AS `category_id`, `ccp`.`product_id`, `ccp`.`position`,
1 AS `is_parent`, 2 AS `store_id`, IFNULL(cpvs.value, cpvd.value) AS `visibility` FROM `catalog_category_entity` AS `cc`
 INNER JOIN `catalog_category_product` AS `ccp` ON ccp.category_id = cc.entity_id
 INNER JOIN `catalog_product_website` AS `cpw` ON cpw.product_id = ccp.product_id
 INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity` AS `cpe` ON ccp.product_id = cpe.entity_id
 INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `cpsd` ON cpsd.entity_id = cpe.entity_id AND cpsd.store_id = 0 AND cpsd.attribute_id = 97
 LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `cpss` ON cpss.entity_id = cpe.entity_id AND cpss.attribute_id = cpsd.attribute_id AND cpss.store_id = 2
 INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `cpvd` ON cpvd.entity_id = cpe.entity_id AND cpvd.store_id = 0 AND cpvd.attribute[...]`
```

products count is 80000.

from server side all configured
`
Thanks